# How should a custom Guice scope be integrated with TestNG?

Tags: java, junit, testng, guice

We use a custom Guice scope, `@TestScoped`, for some of our JUnit tests that lasts for a single test method, and a JUnit `@Rule` to enter and exit the scope appropriately.  It looks like this:

```
public class MyJUnitTest {
    @Rule public CustomRule customRule = new CustomRule(MyModule.class);

    @Inject private Thing thing;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // Use "thing"
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        // Assuming "Thing" is @TestScoped, we'll have a new instance
    }
}
```

We're starting to use TestNG for some of our tests in other projects, and we'd like to have a similar pattern.  So far we've come up with this:

```
@Listeners(CustomTestNGListener.class)
@Guice(modules = MyModule.class)
public class MyTestNGTest {
    @Inject private Provider<Thing> thingProvider;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Thing thing = thingProvider.get();
        // Use "thing"
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Thing thing = thingProvider.get();
        // Assuming "Thing" is @TestScoped, we'll have a new instance
    }
}

public class CustomTestNGListener implements IHookable {
    @Override
    public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {
        TestScope.INSTANCE.enter();
        try {
            callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
        } finally {
            TestScope.INSTANCE.exit();
        }
    }
}
```

There are a couple issues with this design:

- Unlike JUnit, TestNG uses the same instance of the test class for each method.  That means we have to inject `Provider<Thing>` instead of just `Thing`, which is awkward.
- For some reason, `CustomTestNGListener` is running on all of our tests, even ones that don't have that `@Listeners(CustomTestNGListener.class)` annotation.  I've worked around this by explicitly checking for that annotation in the listener itself, but it feels like a hack (though I do see that [MockitoTestNGListener](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/subprojects/testng/src/main/java/org/mockito/testng/MockitoTestNGListener.java) does the same thing).

Does someone with more familiarity with TestNG have any suggestions for dealing with these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
public class MyTestNGTest {
    @Inject private Provider<Thing> thingProvider;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Thing thing = thingProvider.get();
```

In TestNG you can used

```
public class MyTestNGTest {
    @Inject 
    private Thing thingInjected;
    private Thing thing;

    @BeforeTest
    public void doBeforeTest() {
        thing = thingInjected.clone();
    }
```

Or just call `thingProvider.get()` in `doBeforeTest()`, it's better in you have a lot of `@ Test`

```
public class MyTestNGTest {
    @Inject private Provider<Thing> thingProvider;
    private Thing thing;

    @BeforeTest
    public void doBeforeTest() {
        thing = thingProvider.get();
    }
```

Comment: Almost none of our types are clonaeble

Comment: At least, you can call "thing = thingProvider.get();" in  @ BeforeTest not in @ Test. If you have a lot of @ Test, it's better

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin I don't believe this will work when running parallel. So this may not be an option for many people. You are forced to call the get() within the test methods, in parallel.

Comment: I didn't really understate you, if you run MyTestNGTest 10 times, you have 10 instances of MyTestNGTest, that work separately.